# "Living like Jim Morrison" . what does it imply or refer to?

Tags: meaning, lyrics, music, pop-culture

In the Gods and Monsters song by Lana Del Ray “No one’s gonna take my soul away”, there is the line:

> I'm living like Jim Morrison

What does this line mean?

Comment: This is not a question about English, it's a question about rock and roll.

Comment: I found that there are similar questions present on this site which have been answered

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English.

Comment: Any examples of these questions that have been answered?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155233/what-is-the-meaning-of-body-electric

Comment: It's a fair point you're making about "I sing the body electric" question being *on topic* and yours not. Both songs talk about things which I would consider to be in the realm of general knowledge (but I am nearly 50—eek!) and even if they weren't, how difficult is it to Google "Body electric" or "Jim Morrison"? You ought to show some effort of research, explain what you do understand, your guess work, and then say *why* the answer eludes you. It's then easier for users to explain where your confusion lies. A question formed like this is trite, shallow, and lazy.

Comment: If we say this question is on topic, a host of other questions I would rather not see are on topic: *"Lenny Bruce is not afraid, In a coat he borrowed from James Dean. Where have you gone, Joe DiMaggio? Goodbye Norma Jean.* The point being that the meaning of the phrase *"body electric"* in English isn't clear, but the only thing that's not clear in this question is: *who was Jim Morrison?*

Answer (score 2):

> Jim Morrison was the lead singer for The Doors and lived a infamously fast lifestyle. Jim Morrision died from a heroin overdose.
>
> Since Lana is living like Jim Morrison it means that she is living life at an extremely fast pace, with no remorse for the consequences of her actions.
> -- [genius.com](http://pop.genius.com/Lana-del-rey-gods-and-monsters-lyrics#note-2735761)

Comment: what does take my soul away refer to

Comment: Did you even click the link? Literally, the line above that. Click it and it says.

Comment: Jim Morrison is also the name of an infielder who played for the Phillies, White Sox, Pirates, Tigers, and Braves over the course of a twelve-year major league career between 1977 and 1988 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Morrison_%28baseball%29). That Jim Morrison is currently manager of the Charlotte Stone Crabs in the Class A Florida State League. Maybe Lana Del Ray is living like the manager of a Class A minor league baseball team in Port Charlotte, Florida. That would be pretty intense.

Comment: @Sven It would... All the umm bats and baseballs... ;-)

Comment: "You CANNOT petition the manager with prayer!"